# Unable to join AD domain using Kerberos from kickstart

Tags: linux, kerberos, kickstart

I am trying to join to the Windows domain in the `%post chroot` section of my kickstart script using `kinit` and `net` commands after setting up the samba, kerberos and sssd configurations in `%pre`.

My authconfig looks like this in the command section and generates the proper kerb5.conf and smb.conf

`authconfig --disableldap \
    --disablewinbindusedefaultdomain \
    --disablewinbind \
    --disablewinbindauth \
    --smbsecurity=ads \
    --smbworkgroup="$WORKGROUP" \
    --smbrealm="$DOMAIN" \
    --smbservers="$PDC" \
    --enablemkhomedir \
    --enablekrb5 \
    --enablekrb5realmdns \
    --enablekrb5kdcdns \
    --krb5adminserver="$PDC" \
    --krb5kdc="$PDC" \
    --krb5realm="$DOMAIN" \
    --enablelocauthorize \
    --enablepamaccess \
    --nostart \
    --enablesssd \
    --enablesssdauth \
    --kickstart \
    --update`

I can obtain the Kerberos ticket and print it using klist.

```
$ echo -n "$PASS"|kinit ${USER}
$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: linuxadmin@DEV.XXX.LOCAL

Valid starting      Expires            Service pricipal
05/05/15 08:59:08   05/05/15 18:59:07  krbtgt/DEV.XXX.LOCAL@DEV.XXX.LOCAL
        renew until 05/12/15 08:59:08
```

But I always get this error when I run `net` command:

```
$ net ads join -k 
Failed to join domain: failed to join domain 'DEV.XXX.LOCAL' over rpc: Access denied
```

I expect to see the keytab file `/etc/krb5.keytab` but it doesn't get created.

However, when I try to join again after the system reboots, it works fine:

```
Using short domain name -- DEV
Joined 'TEST' to dns domain 'dev.xxx.local'
```

PS. I have also noticed that when I put the build system(%post install stage running in VMware) to `sleep` and ssh to it then joining to the AD domain works without problems.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `authconfig`?

Comment: @ewwhite I have updated my question to include the athconfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work: `net ads join -k -U ${USER}%${PASS}`